# How can I debug a Python script that is called by a bash script in VS Code?

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio-code, debugging

This is a simplified problem, thus the trivial python scripts.

As the title says, I am seeking to debug a python file that is run via a launch task in VS Code. That is, suppose I have the file `script_01.py` open in VS Code. I have set a simple launch task that will run the file `script_02.py` before `script_01.py` is run and debugged.

I want `script_02.py` to be run with the debugger as well. Below are the (simple) contents of the relevant files. (The contents of the python don't matter at this point, since the debugger is not even appearing for `script_02.py`.)

Is this a realistic feature to try and implement?

`.vscode/launch.json` :

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python Debugging Test",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "preLaunchTask": "startup",
        }
    ]
}
```

`.vscode/tasks.json` :

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label" : "startup",
            "type" : "shell",
            "command": "bash task_resources/startup.sh",
       },
    ]
}
```

`task_resources/startup.sh` :

```
python3 script_02.py
```

I have looked at [debugpy](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy), but I was not able to get the python script that is called via bash to be debugged.

Comment: debug a test python script, look at the command line generated, construct the same type of command in the bash script and attach VSC to the debugger, use the same socket number

Comment: use `request: "attach"` in the launch config?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understand you completely, but I've taken the following approach on something similar on my end:

```py
# script_01.py
from subprocess import Popen

proc = Popen(
    args=[
      'python', script_02.py,
      '--arg1', str(1),
      '--arg2', 'some_string_arg',
    ],
)
proc.wait()
# end of script_01.py
```

Then you start debugging `script_01.py`.